# passing arguments from c# to intel x64 assembly through dll

Tags: assembly, x86-64, intel, masm

I am trying to better understand this intel x64 assembly code which is called in a c# program  through a dll. I know what it does but I don't fully understand how the arguments are passed from the main application to the asm function

This is defined in the filter.h file:

```
extern "C" {
    void _kernel_filter(int height, int width, short* source, short* result_rgb, short* kernel, int kerne_value);
}
```

The initial part of the asm code where variable are initialized looks like the following:

```
.code
_kernel_filter proc public
LFB0:
    endbr64
    push    rbp                         ; backup frame pointer 
    mov rbp, rsp                        ; move stack pointer to frame pointer
    mov DWORD PTR -20[rbp], ecx         ; ecx is used to store the first argument:  height -> -20[rbp]
    mov DWORD PTR -24[rbp], edx         ; edx is used to store the second argument: width  -> -24[rbp]
    mov QWORD PTR -32[rbp], r8          ; r8 -> source[] -> -32[rbp]
    mov QWORD PTR -40[rbp], r9          ; r9 -> resut_rgb[] -> -40[rbp]

    mov rax, QWORD PTR[rsp+48]
    mov QWORD PTR -48[rbp], rax         ; r9 -> kernel[] -> -48[rbp]

    mov eax, DWORD PTR [rsp+56]         ; kernel_value
    mov DWORD PTR -52[rbp], eax         ; r9d -> kernel_value
    
    mov eax, DWORD PTR -20[rbp]         ; eax = height
    imul    eax, DWORD PTR -24[rbp]     ; eax = eax* width = width*height
    mov DWORD PTR -4[rbp], eax          ; pixel = width*height -> -4[rbp]
    mov DWORD PTR -12[rbp], 0           ; width_counter -> -12[rbp]
    mov DWORD PTR -8[rbp], 0            ; i = 0 -> -8[rbp]
```

I have not written the comments myself, what I dont understand is:

`mov   DWORD PTR -20[rbp], ecx` so the value in ecx is pointed to by a pointer with some kind of offset to the frame pointer? but why and how does the height find itself in the ecx register?

Bonus question:
why is a dword used for int value and qword for a short which should be smaller than int?

Comment: The code that calls this function put it there, as demanded by the [64-bit calling convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=msvc-170#parameter-passing).  It is not a short, it is a short*.  Pointers are 8-byte values (qword) in 64-bit code.

Comment: Thank you. What would the passing methodology be called? passing via registers? I would like to read up on the matter

Comment: I linked to the doc page, "x64 calling convention".

Comment: Oh got it now! Thanks again

Comment: Beware that the calling convention will differ between operating systems (and of course between architectures).The one linked is specifically for Windows x86_64. In any case, another perhaps more lazy way to get a feel for how an argument of a certain type should be passed (if documentation makes you feel tl;dr) is to simply write a dummy program that calls your function and inspect the assembly output of your compiler and see what ended up where.